# What does it mean when a ManualResetEventSlim is inflated?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm currently reading [ManualResetEventSlim's Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualreseteventslim.aspx).

What does it mean when it says:

> A common use of MRES.WaitHandle is to use MRES as a participant in
> WaitHandle.WaitAll/WaitAny.  Note that accessing MRES.WaitHandle will
> result in the unconditional **inflation** of the underlying
> ManualResetEvent.

What is this **inflation** thing?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *slim* part of `ManualResetEventSlim` is that it does not create an OS-level `ManualResetEvent` until needed.  (those are expensive)

Inflation means creating a real `ManualResetEvent`.

You can see this on line 275 of the [source](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Threading/ManualResetEventSlim@cs/1305376/ManualResetEventSlim@cs).